# Visual Studio Code Editor not Working Properly on Command + S in mac

Tags: reactjs, macos, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, editor

I am not able to figure out why my environment is giving me error on **saving** a file. I destroys the **line spacing and code** after I press **Command + S** to save file.

**Help me out where I am wrong**

Images are showing before and after **pressing Command + S** button in **Mac**
[image: Before pressing Command + S to save file]
[image: After pressing Command + S to save file it gives error]
[image: Before pressing Command + S to save file]
[image: After pressing Command + S to save file it gives error]

Answer (score 0):

There is a setting in vscode to toggle trimming the final newline on save. If you go to Settings, you can find it under Text Editor -> Files -> Trim Final Newlines. Most likely you have this option selected.

Alternatively, in your settings.json file you can add the following line:

```
“files.trimFinalNewLines”: false
```

Comment: If this just started, my guess would be that maybe somewhere this setting got changed. Could be a different workspace setting, your user settings, or maybe the json and ui settings aren’t communicating properly.